# QGIS2web Leaftet Measure Control renders transparent

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

Exporting a map with QGIS2Web renders the Measure Control as transparent with no icon in it or anything.  See the attached image.  I have looked in the CSS and can't find any settings etc. in there to change either.

What is going on?

[image]

Comment: What are your projection ? Do you have the button when you update the preview in QGIS ? Do you have the last version of the plugin ?

Comment: NAD83 UTM Z17,  Yes and Yes

Comment: Have you try to produce the webmap in an empty folder (if you update a map previously uploaded some file can be let). Have you tried a new project with just simple data and nothing else ?

Comment: It previews perfectly, when it writes the html it has no icon in it.  (And the ruler.png is in the right folder etc. in case you were wondering.)

Comment: The programmer of the plugin says there is an issue in the css QGIS2web produces in Chrome and I can fix it after the fact but I can't see where to do that either!  Works fine in Firefox.  Doesn't work in MS Edge either.  Anyone............